# How a list of all a users Google analytics views

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I have many Analytics properties and accounts.

I am now working on JavaScript to get the reports from the Google Analytics API.

In order to make these requests I need the view idea for the account i wish to access so that i can load the related data from the backed.

The only way i have found to find these view ids is to use the [Official GA Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) every time to get the id by selecting *Account* and *Property*.

This is quite annoying. Because it involves human action.

[image: GA Query Explorer screenshot]

Is there any way I can look up the id by the `UA-xxxx` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using the Google Analtyics API to get the reports why not use the Management APi to get a list of all the accounts the user has access to

[Account summeries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) will give you that.

I am not a Javascript developer but the code should be something like this.

```
function queryAccounts() {
  // Load the Google Analytics client library.
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {

    // Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accountSummaries.list().then(handleAccounts);
  });
}
```

Code shamelessly ripped from [Hello Analytics API: JavaScript quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js) and altered a bit using a wild guess.